# Animating an MKOverlayView

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, mapkit, mkoverlay

I have an MKOverlayView that displays animated radar data as a series of images. The issue I have is that the radar images are chopped into tiles by MapKit. To swap images I have a timer that calls an update function which sets the current image in my overlay and then calls the following

```
[myRadarOverlayView setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:self.mapView.visibleMapRect];
```

The overlay updates, but does so one tile at a time so I get a choppy animation. Any ideas about how make all the tiles animate (i.e. swap images) at the exact same time?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a goodf way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by adding a UIImageView as a subview of the MKOverlayView.

- To animate, stop drawing with the
  normal
  drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext: (via
  an instance variable/property flag) and
  draw to the UIImageView instead (to
  the animationImages property), then
  use startAnimating.
- You can handle panning and zooming by
  reinitializing the UIImageView in
  response to
  mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:.

Comment: I'm banging my head on this one too, do you have some sample code to share? I think I'm not setting the frame/bounds right causing the UIImageView not to be shown.

Comment: I was able to use this code here: https://github.com/yickhong/YHMapDemo and this code here: http://code.google.com/p/sugartin-info/downloads/detail?name=RadarOverLay.zip&can=2&q combined together to get the result described in this answer.

Comment: @shawkinaw Could you offer some advice on my question about animating in overlays for map view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558591/animated-gif-not-working-in-mkmapview-overlay-using-mkoverlayrenderer?noredirect=1#comment30789828_20558591?

Comment: I have tried both of the links @Gavin and also from sridvijay  and got radar image appears here but still it takes time to load approx 15-20 secs and got this warning "<Warning>: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.". Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Sample code how to animate a circle:

http://yickhong-ios.blogspot.com/2012/04/animated-circle-on-mkmapview.html

Answer (score 0):

Is there a callback when all the tiles have finished loading? If so, you could go with double buffering, and update the view offscreen, and then switch it in.